# layer styling switches after zooming in with no reason

Tags: polygon, openlayers-2, style

Does anybody have an explanation how it is possible?

I have a strange trouble on the following [map](http://bildungsatlas.map-dienst.de/neuesLayout/ausserschulischeBildung.html). The surrounding land layer, which is only a one polygon layer and is styled normally like:

`var stylePoly = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        fillColor: 'white',
        fillOpacity: 0.85,
        strokeColor: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1
        });`

is switching to the non-surrounding area when zooming to a certain level. It only happens when the focus is on a bbox where the surrounding land is to be seen.

What should I change to get the appearance constant? I do not really understand this behavior. Maybe somebody had the same problem already...

The data is gml and the visibility of the layer is constantly "true"...

Layer is created like:

```
var protocolUmland = new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: 'http://bildungsatlas.map-dienst.de/gml/FHH_Umland.gml', 
        format: gml
        }); 

var Umland = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Umland', 
    {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: protocolUmland,
    styleMap: stylePoly,
    visibility: true
    }
);
```